# Data Definition Language (DDL) Query SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ddl

I'm new in query and SQL server, and I wanted to know about DDL.
I have an attribute in my Table which has more than 1 value, such as
Size = {'S', 'M', 'L'}.
How could i make the attribute in my Table with query, so i can insert multi values  to one of my attribute?

Comment: You don't insert multiple attributes into one row.  You insert multiple rows into a table.

Comment: Look up One to Many relationships, you would use two tables for this kind of thing

Comment: Product (...,ProductSize);
INSERT INTO Product
    (ProductSize)
    VALUES ('S')

How to query the row of ProductSize so i can insert more than one values in SQL?

Comment: @Brad advice is correct here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to do this, because this is denormalizing your data. But, if you must.

```
declare @table table (id int identity(1,1),  size varchar(16))

insert into @table
values
('S')
,('M')

select * from @table

update @table
set size = size + ',M'
where id = 1

select * from @table
```

Here is a one to many approach with a foreign key

```
create table #items (id int identity(1,1), descrip varchar(64))

insert into #items
values
('shirt'),
('pants')

create table #item_sizes (id int identity(1,1), size char(1), item_id int)
alter table #item_sizes
add constraint FK_item foreign key (item_id) references #items(id)

insert into #item_sizes
values
('S',1)
,('M',1)
,('L',1)
,('S',2)

select 
    ItemID = i.id
    ,i.descrip
    ,isiz.size
from #items i
inner join #item_sizes isiz
on isiz.item_id = i.id


drop table #items, #item_sizes
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement :

Product (...,ProductSize);

```
 INSERT INTO Product (ProductSize) VALUES ('S')
```

How to query the row of ProductSize so i can insert more than one values in SQL? –

you can query like below

```
 select * from Product where ProductSize like '%S%' or ProductSize like '%L%' or ProductSize like '%M%'
```